# How can I use jQuery to remove only a subset of table rows based on a TD class?

Tags: jquery

If I have a simple table like this:

```
<table>
<tr class ="tableRow"><td>Teacher #1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="detail">Susan</td></tr>
<tr><td class="detail">AM</td></tr>

<tr class="tableRow"><td>Teacher #2</td></tr>
<tr><td class="detail">Tom</td></tr>
<tr><td class="detail">PM</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have code that removes all of the table rows that contain a TD with a class of "detail":

```
$('tr td.detail').each(function(){
$(this).parent().remove(); }
```

However, I only want it to remove the detail TDs under Susan when I click on the row with her name, not Tom's. And vice versa.. instead of just removing them ALL.

I'm already in a function that runs when a table row is clicked:
`$(".tableRow").on('click',function(){ ... });`, so I figured there'd be a way to check, say, the next two table rows to see if there are any detail TDs.

Any way to do that?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com) -> [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/), [`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Comment: Please be explicit: which row are you clicking?   *when I click on the row with her name* / *`$(".tableRow").click`- doesn't have her name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.nextUntil()` to match all the rows until `.tableRow`.

```
$(".detail").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextUntil(".tableRow").remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: .nextUntil() for the win, but I can't define a function like that inside of another function. 

I'd like it to remove the detail TDs only when someone clicks on a table row, so is there an .each or something that I call that starts with the table low that I've clicked?

Comment: Figured it out with .nextUntil():

`$(this).nextUntil(".tableRow").remove();`

Only fires when you click a .tableRow table row and removes everything until it gets to the next .tableRow. Thank you!